# Unable to connect to MySQL through PHP, mysql works, but not using mysqli or PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

In my connect script this works, but will be deprecated.

```
$dbLink = mysql_connect($dbHostname, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$dbselected = mysql_select_db($dbDatabase,$dbLink) or die("Could not select database");
```

If I change it to use either a PDO or mysqli it fails with

> "No database selected"

on my test pc, or

> "Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

on my live site.

```
 $dbLink = mysqli_connect($dbHostname, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbDatabase);
```

Read and tested the similar question with the `ini_get("mysqli.default_port")..` The new commands connect ok, but then nothing completes.

My PDO code is

```
$dbLink = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mass', $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
```

Comment: It's saying `using password: NO`. That means that `$dbPassword` is empty.

Comment: Show your pdo connection code.

Comment: Show us your PDO or mysqli connection string

Comment: @asprin The *mysqli* example is already part of the question. I think Barmar has hit the nail on the head; the password is empty

Comment: @Phil Ah right..mistook it for mysql..

Comment: So now the only difference is the addition of the 'i" as in mysqli between the 2 lines of code. When I use mysqli I get the error "Could not select database". Is this syntax not valid? I thought the number of parameters had changed between the 2. If I use the PDO code above there is no error message just a blank screen.

Comment: I added in your mysqli code and after that line I put 4 echo statements and they contained the correct values. I then got on the screen "Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" So after it is connecting something does not like it. The code base has then a lot of include statements, with the old style code. I guess I'll have to pull it all apart.

Comment: @PeterBrooks As Barmar said in the first comment, this means that you're passing an empty password

Comment: Rather than use variables (which may be empty), why not use literal strings (see my answer below), at least until you get it working?

Comment: I have tried hard-coding the values. It seems to be something that is happening after the connection - some clash. I started this process to clean up all the old mysql_ commands and I started at the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your main problem is relying on `or die()` to handle error conditions. This won't work as neither the `PDO` nor `mysqli` constructor will return a *falsey* value.

Instead, you should use the appropriate level of error handling.

#### Development environment

While developing, always work with the following properties in your `php.ini` file

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

You may need to restart your web server (if you're using one) after making changes to this file.

#### mysqli

Check the `connect_errno` property for a connection error state

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    throw new Exception($mysqli->connect_error, $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

#### PDO

The `PDO` constructor *should* throw an exception if it can't connect. Setting the error mode to *exception* means that any further errors will also throw an exception.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
]);
```

I wouldn't bother with any `try {...} catch` statements while you're developing, at least not in this initial stage as you're likely to end up hiding any serious errors.

Comment: I used your PDO example with the values hard-coded. All I get is a blank screen. Which tells me the Connection seems to work, it is the following code that is incompatible?

Comment: @PeterBrooks Did you set up error reporting as outlined at the top of my post?

Comment: I have error reporting turned up full on my in-house PC. I just checked the error_log file online and see an error relating to PDO: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /home/..
Also this error when testing the mysqli_
PHP Warning:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home..
PHP Version: 5.5.10

Comment: The first means you haven't enabled the PDO extension. The second is completely unnecessary as in my example, the database name is already included in the mysqli constructor